# XSLT - Sort alphabetically in a for loop

Tags: xml, loops, sorting, xslt, alphabetical

I am trying to sort users from my XML file, alphibetically, using an XSLT.

Here is the XML sample

```
<ROOT>
    <ROW>
        <FULLNAME>Adam Low</FULLNAME>
        <GROUPS>
            <DEPARTMENT>Test 1</DEPARTMENT>
            <DEPARTMENT>Test 2</DEPARTMENT>
        </GROUPS>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FULLNAME>Julie Nelson</FULLNAME>
        <GROUPS>
            <DEPARTMENT>Test 1</DEPARTMENT>
            <DEPARTMENT>Test 2</DEPARTMENT>
        </GROUPS>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FULLNAME>Colin Low</FULLNAME>
        <GROUPS>
            <DEPARTMENT>Test 1</DEPARTMENT>
        </GROUPS>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FULLNAME>Bobby Low</FULLNAME>
        <GROUPS>
            <DEPARTMENT>Test 1</DEPARTMENT>
        </GROUPS>
    </ROW>
</ROOT>
```

And here is how I think the the XSLT should look

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <strong>Users</strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ROW/GROUPS">
                            <xsl:if test="DEPARTMENT = 'Test 1'">
                                <xsl:sort select="../FULLNAME" />
                                <xsl:value-of select="../FULLNAME" />
                                <br />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In short I'm looping through every `ROW` in the `ROOT` and every `DEPARTMENT` within the `GROUPS` node to fine 'Test 1' at which point I pull out the value of the `FULLNAME` node a level up, and write it into a `<TD>`, I want alphbetically order every value I put into the `<TD>`. Currently where I have `<xsl:sort select="../FULLNAME" />` is not working.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't tell us something "isn't working", tell us how it fails.

Comment: @MichaelKay

Hi Michael, at the time of writing I did not understand the error messages the the processor was throwing. I did try researching them before posting the question, I was also short on time.

The error the code above was producing was:

"SaxonCE.StandardErrorListener 11:29:25.549
SEVERE: Error at /xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/xsl:for-each/xsl:if/xsl:sort in http://fiddle.frameless.io/
  XTSE0010: An xsl:if element must not contain an xsl:sort element"

On reflection I understand the message now; at the time, being new to XSL, I didnt find it much help.

Comment: It's a common problem. People don't understand the error message, so they don't post it, because they imagine that no-one else will understand it either. The error message says exactly what's wrong: the xsl:sort is misplaced. But it also refers to two different client-side XSLT processors (Saxon-CE and Frameless), neither of which is actively maintained:  I think you would be well off finding a better development/test environment (e.g. an IDE such as oXygen or Stylus Studio) which will give you better diagnostics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express the condition in a predicate

```
<xsl:for-each select="ROW/GROUPS[DEPARTMENT = 'Test 1']">
  <xsl:sort select="../FULLNAME" />
```

then the `xsl:sort` is in the right position.